# Can I write to the resource fork using NSDocument?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdocument

I'd like to store some additional information along with a document, but I can't use bundles or packages, and I cannot store it inside the document itself.

The application is a text editor, and I'd like it to store code folding and bookmark locations with the document, but obviously this cannot be embedded into the code directly, and I don't want to alter the code with ugly comments.

Can I use NSDocument to store information in the resource fork of a document? If so, how can I do this? Should I directly write to `<filename>/..namedfork/rsrc` or is there an API available?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, don't use the resource fork. It's virtually deprecated. Instead, use extended attributes. They can be set programmatically at the BSD level via [`setxattr`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/setxattr.2.html) and [`getxattr`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/getxattr.2.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/2/getxattr). Extended attributes are used in many places... for example, in the latest OS X, the resource fork itself is implemented as a special type of extended attributes.

For example, the Cocoa text system automatically adds an extended attribute to a file to specify the encoding.

I thought `NSFileManager` and `NSFileWrapper` supported extended attributes since Snow Leopard, but I can't find any documentation :p You can always use the BSD level functions, though.

Answer (score 1):

Does the state need to move with the file if it's copied to another computer? If not, you could do a lot worse than emulating the way Bare Bones handles document state with BBEdit. They store state for all documents in ~/Library/Preferences/com.barebones.bbedit.PreferenceData/Document State.plist.

The resource fork documentation [is here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/Resource_Manager/Reference/reference.html). But it contains plenty of suggestions to not use the resource fork.

Answer (score 0):

I have a class on my web site for reading and writing resource forks, which I have never got around to moving to my GitHub repository because, as Yuji points out, they are not really used any more.

I was going to say alias files and web Internet location file are the only places they are used, but I used and tested it on [Mac OS X v10.7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Lion) (Lion), and they are not even used there any more; they may still be used for custom icons. I didn't test for that exclusively. I will have to see how that affect my NDAlias class on 10.7.

[ndresourcefork](http://homepage.mac.com/nathan_day/pages/source.xml)

Comment: Dear Nathan, nice to see you here! I used your `NDAlias` in my project which helped me greatly. (I moved to the official bookmark API in `NSURL`, though.)

Comment: Yeah I have heard about that I will have to look into it.